# Grab user geolocation an pass it into contact form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to set a certain form with WP CF7 and would like to grab the exact user geolocation and pass it into the mail sent to the admin, something like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

only instead of printing lon and lat results -> pass it in mail, perhaps using cookies? (store it and then read it?)

I appreciate any help,
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using WooCommerce by any chance?  You can tap their Geolocation feature.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `navigator.watchPosition` so you don't have a popup in the Browser again. Do like:

```
let lat, lng;
navigator.watchPosition(position=>{
  const pos = position.coords;
  const undef = lat === undefined;
  lat = pos.latitude; lng = pos.longitude;
  if(undef){
    latElement.value = lat; lngElement.value = lng;
  }
}, error=>{
  throw new Error(error.message);
}, {enableHighAccuracy:true});
someLatLngUpdateButton.onclick = ()=>{
  latElement.value = lat; lngElement.value = lng;
}
```

Of course, this design would assign `lat` and `lng` only if they haven't been, then update them when you hit a button. You could constantly update the Elements, but that might be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send the user position within the CF7 email, you need a field with the value of the coordinates returned by your function. Here is an example.

```
<label> Your name
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your e-mail
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
    [text* your-subject] </label>

<label> Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[hidden position id:position]

<script type="text/javascript">
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    document.getElementById('position').value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  document.getElementById('position').value = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
}
getLocation();
</script>

[submit "Submit"]
```